# Form Resizing Responsive issue textarea

Tags: html, css, forms, textarea, responsive-design

I've got an issue with my responsive textarea. It works fine (across different sizes) until the user tries to expand the form (I've currently got it locked in size with a height/max-height/width/max-width combo). Is there a solution to this? What am I doing wrong - haven't seen this issue before.

Album - 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7Cgt.jpg

Website - 
http://pxlprfct.co.uk/

Html

```
<textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
```

Css

```
form{
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: black;

    /*Android Hack*/
    margin-top: -1px;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
}

    #message
{
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: black;

    display: block;
    background: white;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;

    height: 12em;
    max-height: 12em;

    width: 70%;
    max-width: 70%;

}
```

Sorry about the messy code - it's all been hacked together quickly! :) 
Thanks in advance!


http://jsfiddle.net/qfYQN/1/

Comment: I don't understand the issue, can you explain it better? Thanks :)

Comment: Does this help? http://jsfiddle.net/qfYQN/1/ - Sorry for the terrible explanation

Comment: I am not understanding what you exactly want to achieve, should the user be able to resize the textarea horizontally?

Comment: There is actually a resize property in css that you can use to disable the feature of user resizing. Just set resize:none.

Comment: So to clarify: When resizing the window, the text box grows and shrinks correctly and stays in the center of the page. However, once the user has resized the textbox, it doesnt shrink and grow correctly anymore?

Comment: @René Geuze - Thanks for that, added it, and now its not re-sizable, and all works perfectly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of a solid resolution to this issue.

The way I see it, you have two options: Disable the resize css property or use some javascript to reset the margin to auto when the user resizes the box.

css:

```
 resize:none;
```

jquery:
Unfortunately there is not an event listener for a text box resizing so this would be the simplest method:

```
 $('#message').mouseup(function(){
    $(this).css('margin', 'auto');  
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WLBde/

Otherwise you could set an interval that checks the width of the text box every X seconds and if it is different then reset the margins like above.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I didn't know that there was a css re-size property! That clears everything up :) Set "resize:none" and now it works perfectly :) Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I made this work.  I just assigned the text area an id of message,
then I added this css

```
#message {

    width:100%;

}
```